# How to solve this Timeslot issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to solve this business issue:

- A user gets 10 attempts to login every 5 minutes
- If a user exceeds 10 attempts, I display a "You need to wait to
  login" message
- Once 5 minutes have elapsed, I need to reset the number of attempts
  and let the user attempt 10 more times.

I'd like to do this without using a `Timer` and I am storing most of this info in the `Session`

```
public class LoginExp
{
  public DateTime FirstAttempt;
  public int NumOfAttempts;
}
```

I store the `FirstAttempt` DateTime on Page Load.

On the Login button click:

- I increment `NumOfAttempts`
- I need to check if NumOfAttempts < 10 ***within*** the same 5 minute time slot. I could get the number of minutes elapsed between `FirstAttempt` and `DateTime.Now` and do a mod of 5, but that won't tell me which timeslot this is in (In other words, a user may have attempted 3 times as of the 2nd minute and then comes back in the 7th minute to do an attempt again. The `mod` would give me the same value.

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Comment: this way (storing it on Session) the user will get unlimited attempts if he resets session (deletes cookies) each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a list of attempt timestamps and use that to determine if the user is locked out. This is not complete code, but here's the basic idea:

```
// Store a list of attempts
var attempts = new List<DateTime>();

// Determine if 10 or more attempts have been made in the last 5 minutes
bool lockout = attempts.Where(a => (DateTime.Now - a).TotalMinutes <= 5).Count() >= 10;

// Register an attempt
attempts.Add(DateTime.Now);

// Remove attempts older than 5 minutes
attempts.Where(a => (DateTime.Now - a).TotalMinutes > 5).ToList()
    .ForEach(a => attempts.Remove(a));
```

You could also store the attempts in a database, which would give you a papertrail for security purposes. The same methodology would apply -- count the records less than 5 minutes old.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a timer, please. Make room for this data alongside the user data, to be persisted, where some form of their credentials is stored. Just keep a last login attempt time and number of attempts - if the time is greater than *n* then the next attempt clears the previous count and starts from 0, and so on.

Comment: My issue is how I would calculate `n` even if I store the last login time.

Comment: -1 this doesn't actually solve the OP request for 10 in 5 minutes.
If there is an attempt every 4 minutes this will count out indefinitely.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor That there might be loopholes where logic is concerned, the point here is to persist the data somewhere reliable, that your logic, if done correctly, can rely on.

Comment: @DotnetDude The time period is up to you, can either be part of your logic relying on the data or you could pull that from a dedicated data source, then do a comparison based on the last login attempt time and the current time to see if the timespan is greater than whatever _n_ is, wherever _n_ is from.

Comment: @Grant Thomas The question is how to accomplish restricting to 10 in 5 minutes, the method you propose is flawed in that respect. The hole isn't in the logic, it is in what data you suggest persisting. Persisting the right data is as important as the logic. Without the correct data, no logic can be done correctly. See my answer for an explanation of why last time+ count is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you interpret the requirement. Namely, is the 5-minute time frame a sliding scale?

A rigid application of the requirement would require you to create a database table for login attempts, with each record including the key to the user record and a timestamp of the login attempt. Then for each attempt, execute a query like

```
delete from login_attempts where user=[user] and attempt_time<[now - 5 minutes]
select count(*) from login_attempts where user=[user]
```

(where the bracketed values are replaced with suitable values, whether you use a prepared statement or whatever)

Then if the returned count > 10, you block the attempt.

(I suggest deleting old attempts every time through to keep the table clean. Alternative methods are, of course, possible.)

If the requirement need not be applied that rigidly and you don't want to create a new table, you could simplify it by, for example, adding last attempt time and count to the user record. Then on each attempt (pseudocode here ...):

```
read last_attempt and attempt_count
if last_attempt < now - 5 minutes then
  attempt_count=0
endif
if attempt_count>10 then
  display error
else if attempt_fails then
  last_attempt=now
  attempt_count=attempt_count+1
endif
```

This wouldn't strictly meet the stated requirements: If the user tried once every 4 minutes, then after 40 minutes we'd say he had 10 bad tries, when in fact all but one of those were more than 5 minutes ago. But it would be simpler then creating a new table and would achieve what I presume is the goal, stopping someone from cracking a password by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a sliding 5 minute window you need to know the time of each attempt, not just the first one or last one.

Store in a database each login attempt. As was mentioned in comments, just using the session cache is easily circumvented.

```
username     | time
mr.mindor    | 00:00:00
mr.mindor    | 00:01:00
```

etc.
then for each login attempt check that there are 10 or fewer attempts...

```
Select count(*) 
from LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 
  where username = @current_user 
  AND time > DATEADD(m,-5,GetDate())
```

You can retain the LOGIN_ATTEMPTS indefinitely for security/auditing purposes or clear it out periodically, or with a successful login.

**Problems with storing only first or last time and count.**
Without each time, you cannot determine the distribution of the attempts.

**First Attempt based solution:**

With just the first attempt time and count you can prevent more than 10 attempts in the 5 minutes following first, but not prevent more than 10 attempts in any given 5 minute interval.
Example: you could have 1 at 0:00 and 9 at 4:59, and allow 10 more at 5:01 for 19 in a few seconds.

```
attempt_time | record
0:00         | {0:00, 1}
4:59         | {0:00, 2}
4:59         | {0:00, 3}
4:59         | {0:00, 4}
4:59         | {0:00, 5}
4:59         | {0:00, 6}
4:59         | {0:00, 7}
4:59         | {0:00, 8}
4:59         | {0:00, 9}
4:59         | {0:00, 10}  
5:01         | {5:00, 1}  // 10 since 4:59
5:02         | {5:00, 2}  // 11 since 4:59
```

**Last Attempt based solution:**
Saving just the last attempt time and a count you can prevent more than 10 attempts in any 5 minute interval, but it is actually far more restrictive. It becomes prevent more than 10 attempts that are each within 5 minutes of the previous attempt.
Example: If there are attempts every 4 minutes your counter will never reset.

```
attempt_time | record
0:00         | {0:00, 1}
4:00         | {4:00, 2}  // 2 in last 5 minutes
8:00         | {8:00, 3}  // 2 in last 5 minutes
...
40:00        | {40:00,11} // blocked but only 2 in last 5 minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer is ugly here.
Just keep an Attempts table of some sort.
Store UserId, Time of attempt, and a success/fail flag.

From there the logic is self explanatory.